# Question regarding the onclick attribute of <rich:tab>

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have the following code:

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="client">
    <rich:tab name="tab1" label="tab1" onclick="alert('Hello');">
        ...
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab name="tab2" label="tab2" onclick="alert('Hi');">
        ...
    </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

This code will generate a panel with 2 tab headers, like that:

```
+------+ +------+
| tab1 | | tab2 |
+      +-+------+--------------------------+
|                                          |
|    Content of my Tab goes here...        |
|                                          |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Regarding the code used, I would expect to see a JavaScript alert saying `Hi` if I click on the `tab2` header.

However, nothing is displayed, and I just switch to the second tab.

In fact, if I click on the **content** of the tab, the alert message is displayed.

I am a bit confused regarding this behavior.

**Question #1** Is this behavior normal? In others words, the `onclick` refers to the click event on the content and **not** on the tab header.

Indeed, if I look at this [post](http://community.jboss.org/message/22753#22753) and this related [defect](http://jira.jboss.com/jira/browse/RF-123), it does not seem to be correct...

**Question #2** If this behavior is normal, how can I set a different `onclick` behavior for each tab? Indeed, if I set the `onclick` on the `<rich:tabPanel>` instead of the `<rich:tab>` component, the `onclick` javascript function will always be executed.

I am using Richfaces 3.3.2.GA, JSF 1.2 + Facelets, Java 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After browsing the Richfaces forum and especially this [bug](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/RF-1084), as well as the code of this component, I found that there is a `onlabelclick` attribute that does exaclty what I want to do.

So the answer for my first question is **Yes**, and the working code for the second question is:

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="client">
    <rich:tab name="tab1" label="tab1" onlabelclick="alert('Hello');">
        ...
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab name="tab2" label="tab2" onlabelclick="alert('Hi');">
        ...
    </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

I wasn't aware of this attribute because the [site](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tabPanel.jsf) and the [developer guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_tab.html) of Richfaces do not tell anything about them, and my Eclipse IDE + JBoss Tools plugin didn't include them in the autocompletion mechanism.

Comment: Do you know why I can't use "return false" to end the navigation towards the tab in the onlabel click event?

Comment: changed to onheaderclick in richfaces 4